# Rails3 create method issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Subscription
 => Subscription(id: integer, email: string, tuan: boolean, send: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Subscription.create("email"=>"dd")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
    from /home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:69:in `send'
    from /home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1548:in `block in attributes='
    from /home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1544:in `each'
    from /home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1544:in `attributes='
    from /home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1411:in `initialize'
```

I used the above code. I want to use the create method to persist a record to db,
but it throws an error. I am new to rails3. I have checked my syntax, didn't find any error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out by myself. In subscription model, I used a `send` column.

`Send` may be a keyword of rails so it threw an error. After I changed it to some other word e.g. 'subscribe', then it works fine.

(I have encounted this issue when used a column named "type" too)

Comment: Here's a list to get you started: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/reservedwords. Google "rails reserved words" for others -- there is no "official" one so far as I know.

Comment: True. List of reserved keywords - http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords

Answer (score 0):

Did you override your initialize in your Subscription model?